# Reverse engineering code

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering

I am currently doing an assignment where I have to write a code to decrypt a text file that is given to me. I am just stuck on how to reverse engineer the encrypting code, which is as follow:

```
char decode(char aChar)
{
  int result = 1 + (rand() % 127);
  result = aChar - result;

  if (result < 0)
  {
    result = result - 128;
  }
  return result;
}
```

My code works but when I run the program it encrypts the already encrypted text file. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: That's quite tricky: one thing you'll need to do is back out your random number generator. Possible (assuming a linear conguential generator), but not trivial.

Comment: What does your encrypt code look like?  Do you seed `rand` with the same key?

Comment: @NathanOliver: I don't think that's necessary. You call `rand()` again, and back out all the generated numbers prior to that.

Comment: _"My code works but [actually doesn't]"_ On what test data? _"when I run the program"_ Where is *the* program? This seems like a very incomplete question.

Comment: @Bathsheba Maybe, but most decode this string assignments just have you resuse the seed that was used to encrypt the string.  If the OP was lucky and had a good implementation of rand they might not even be able to rewind it.

Comment: The encrypting code is called `decode`?

Comment: I'm returning the decoded result right @aschepler

Comment: Why are you *subtracting* 128 if result is negative.  Shouldn't you be adding it?

Comment: None of the values when `result` is negative are representable as a `char`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to know how the random numbers are generated.

Suppose it is generated using `srand()` with a constant seed like this:

```
unsigned int seed = 1;
srand(seed);
```

Then the decryption code might be something like:

```
char decrypt(char aChar)
{
  srand(seed);
  int result = 1 + (rand() % 127);

  if (aChar + 128 < 0)
        aChar = aChar + 128;

   aChar = aChar + result;

  return aChar;
}
```

Note that this is not necessarily works 100% as the `if` statement in the `decode` function makes it difficult to decrypt all characters because it can generate probable results that need more work.

Comment: That is wrong code; `aChar` and `result` are always combined.

Comment: @Adder: what do you mean?

Comment: It is ok now, you changed the code.

Comment: @Yoginth: I think your `decode` function needs revision too.

Comment: @Adder: copy/paste :). Thanks!